# Save a Pandas DataFrame to a CSV file without adding extra double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula, quoting

I want to save a Pandas dataframe to a CSV file in such a way that no additional double quotes or any other characters are added to these formulas. Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Column1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Column2": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "Formula": ['"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.yahoo.com"",""See Yahoo"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"",""See Google"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.bing.com"",""See Bing"")"']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file without adding extra double quotes
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, doublequote=False)
```

But this throws this error:
  `File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`

How can I bypass this? I need it so that the hyperlink shows in Excel as a clickable link.

Comment: How did those extra quotes get in the data? Is it literally written in your code or did you read it from some other source? You have python strings that themselves are some sort of string literal. You could likely do an `ast.tieral_eval` on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the double quotes `""` from the hyperlinks:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Column1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Column2": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "Formula": [
        '=HYPERLINK("https://www.yahoo.com", "See Yahoo")',
        '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "See Google")',
        '=HYPERLINK("https://www.bing.com", "See Bing")',
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, quotechar='"')
```

Creates `out.csv`:

```
Column1,Column2,Formula
1,A,"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.yahoo.com"", ""See Yahoo"")"
2,B,"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"", ""See Google"")"
3,C,"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.bing.com"", ""See Bing"")"
```

---

Opening the CSV in LibreOffice (Ctrl+Click on the formula opens a webpage):

[image]

Comment: In the Russian layout, to make it work, I had to replace the function name with Russian, commas - with semicolons, and set the encoding to 1251. `'=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА("https://www.yahoo.com"; "See Yahoo")'`,  `df.to_csv("out.csv", sep=";", index=False, encoding='cp1251')`